# Z-index not working on samsung galaxy tab?

Tags: android, html, css, z-index, galaxy-tab

Im working on this project for work atm where an e-learning will be played on the samsung galaxy tab. the game is just a website but will be showed as app.

When you log in for the first time you will see a popup with this welcome message, behind it is a black overlay with transparancy.

The problem is that on the PC while on firefox it all works great but on the tablet the Z-index doesnt seem to work. its impossible to debug and I couldnt find any documentation on this issue.
So does anyone know if z-index works differently on the tablet or how do I fix it?

The pop up has z-index 999 and the overlay is z-index 998, 
Any ideas on this?
I will continue my search on google and will post all the progress I make.

Edit:
The overlay will be created in Jquery:
var showPopup = '<%=ViewData("showPopup").toString()%>'

```
if (showPopup == "True") { $('body').prepend('<div class="overlay"></div>'); $('#welcomeBox').show(); }
```

Solved now, see comment for solution.

Comment: Found the answer, the answer was partially on stackoverflow can be found here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562206/android-webkit-absolutely-positioned-elements-dont-respect-z-index

The rest was found in an tutorial.
The solution was the following:

I added the overlay in jQuery but the pop up was in the html but just hidden. so I added that part of the code also to the jQuery check.
To prevent the pop up inheriting the opacity of the overlay I had to use the `$('body').prepend` again.

It all works now.
had to put in in here since im not allowed to answer my own questions yet :(

Comment: I will post the solution above as answer in 6 hours when I can ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer,
the answer was partially on stackoverflow can be found here: [Android Webkit: Absolutely positioned elements don't respect z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562206/android-webkit-absolutely-positioned-elements-dont-respect-z-index)

The rest was found in an tutorial.

The solution was the following:

I added the overlay in jQuery but the pop up was in the html but just hidden.
so I added that part of the code also to the jQuery check.
To prevent the pop up inheriting the opacity of the overlay I had to use the `$('body').prepend` again. It all works now.

Answer (score 10):

Late to the party but, I found the best solution for this was to add -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); to the item that is absolute positioned and z-indexed.
Has solved my issue every time.

Comment: This worked for me with Samsung Galaxy S2 running Android 4.0.4